# Dúvida sobre a função Explode -PHP

Tags: php

Após eu desenvolver uma novo funcionalidade no sistema o meu supervisor pediu para que eu não utiliza-se a função EXPLODE  pois a mesma consome grande quantidade de memória no servidor.

A função explode e realmente tão ruim para trabalhar com uma grande quantidade de requisições? se sim qual função pode substituir ela?

Comment: Mas o seu supervisor recomendou o que no lugar do `explode()`? Expressões regulares(dependendo da tarefa)?  `preg_split()`? Cara, vai de `explode()` mesmo. Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303235/in-php-which-is-faster-preg-split-or-explode

Comment: No caso o objetivo é localizar uma parte especifica de uma string , para isso ele pediu para eu utilizar strrpos  e substr .

Comment: Pode usar explode sim. Seria interessante você editar sua pergunta e por o código. Mas o uso do `explode()`, ainda faz sentido neste caso. Veja a segunda resposta mais votada, o uso do explode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030779/splitting-strings-in-php-and-get-last-part

Comment: Muito Obrigado,mas uma coisa ainda não ficou clara para mim , Explode() continua viável mesmo com um grande número de requisições? Pois como já disse, meu supervisor usou como argumento  que essa função consome muito memória quando recebe um número pesado de requisições.

Answer (score 0):

Há dois tipos em  php `explode()` e o `preg_split()`
Baixo você pode ver a diferença entre os dois

Em um uso simples explode() é muito mais rápido,

Mas  o  preg_split tem as vantagens de usar o caracter do <kbd>tab</kbd> (\t) e espaço <kbd>Space</kbd> com \s.
e alem disso poder usar regex para dividir em varias seções, o  que pode deixa-lo mais pesado

O metacaracter \s é usado para encontrar um caracter em branco

Neste caso você pode ver qual melhor usar em seu seguimento.

Uma dica, use array_filter para apagar itens vazios na sua array de retorno

Exemplo:

```
$keyword = explode(' ', $_GET['search']); //or preg_split
print_r($keyword);

$keyword = array_filter($arr, 'empty');
print_r($keyword);
```

**

> [referencias do  forum em ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303235/in-php-which-is-faster-preg-split-or-explode)

**